# How can i use socket.io with my chat in react native app using Rest Api

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I am performing chat module using Rest Apis in React native app i want to make it real time how can i use Socket.io with it.here is my code where i am fetching message and send messages with a person how to make all this real time with socket.io. Please help

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchMessages();
  }
  fetchMessages = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectUid");
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch(
      CONSTANT.BaseUrl + "chat/list_user_messages?current_id=" + Pid + "&reciver_id=" + params.receiver_id + "&msg_id=" + params.message_id
    );
    const json = await response.json();

    if (Array.isArray(json) && json[0] && json[0].type && json[0].type === 'error') {
      this.setState({ fetchMessageDetail: [] ,isLoading:false}); // empty data set 
    } else {
      this.setState({ fetchMessageSenderDetail: json.chat_sidebar , isLoading:false });
      this.setState({ fetchMessageDetail: json.chat_nodes , isLoading:false });

    }
  };
  SendMessage = async () => {
    const { message } = this.state;
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const Uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectUid");
    if (message == "") {
      //alert("Please enter Email address");
      this.setState({ email: "Please add message" });

    } else {
      axios
        .post(
          CONSTANT.BaseUrl + "chat/sendUserMessage",
          {
            sender_id: Uid,
            receiver_id: params.receiver_id,
            message:message,
          }
        )
        .then(async response => {
          this.setState({
            message:''
          })
          this.fetchMessages();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
```

Comment: Hi socket.io have it's communication style with WebSocket , you need to set up a socket server and install socket.io-client into your React native app